# Tensorial decomposition of $B(H)$

Tags: banach-algebras, c-star-algebras, oa.operator-algebras, tensor-products, fa.functional-analysis

Let $H$ be an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space and let $\mathcal{B}(H)$ be the (C*/W*-)algebra of bounded operators on it. Actually, you may forget about the involution in $\mathcal{B}(H)$ because I am interested in $\mathcal{B}(H)$ only as a Banach algebra (operator algebra).

Do there exist two **infinite-dimensional** Banach algebras $A, B$ such that $\mathcal{B}(H)$ is isomorphic as a Banach algebra to the **projective tensor product** $A\otimes_\gamma B$?

You may also replace the projective tensor product by any other Banach algebra tensor product which arises from a **reasonable crossnorm** (so the vNA tensor product is not good).

Comment: No. Even the Banach algebra structure is irrelevant here. ${\cal B}(H)$ (and its kin) is not Banach isomorphic to a reasonable tensor product of two infinite-dimensional Banach spaces. The proof involves a few deep known facts about Banach space structure of ${\cal B}(H)$ and this margin is too small to contain it.

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA, but there is enough space to put that proof in the answer box below

Comment: @Norbert please see here https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.3621

Comment: @TomekKania, you should post this as an answer!

Comment: @Norbert this does not answer the question as the paper deals only with C*-tensor norms.